# Supporting Web Services from a Win/MFC/C++ App

Tags: c++, windows, wcf, iis

I am looking for the best way to add support for a REST based Web Service to an MFC C++ Application. This is legacy code that has been around a long time.

I need to have the Application provide the Web Service.  I've researched this, and the articles are about consuming Web Services in a C++ App.  I envision having to monitor a port and respond to the HTTP requests.  It would probably make more sense to tie in with WCF and IIS, but I am not sure how to move forward.

I already have a tool of "making" this App into a Windows Service.  I realize it would be better to have a "real" app, and this is what I have to work with.  There is so much logic in this code and we are limited in development time, so we are taking the fastest approach possible.  We also cannot use DCOM, as the Web Service will be called by a Linux based system.

Any suggested articles would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ you can test two libraries [WSF/C](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/c/) and [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), another alternative is to develop it with C# and WCF , and communicate between C# and C++ using C++\CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The WSF/C library looks like it is primarily C based, and works with SOAP based web services.   I actually have used gSoap in the past on an App to consume web services.  I'll revisit it's use for server web services.  Although, this too seems to be SOAP based service support.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) Net c++ library for this as it supports both HTTP client and server functionality. I considered various other libraries including Boost based stuff, but other than Poco I struggled to find everything I needed in one tidy package. It also has some easy to use mutex support which became essential for me as soon as I added a web server front-end to what had previously been a simple single threaded console app. Poco is cross platform but I mainly use it windows and it has served me well to date. I'm not very clued up on MFC so I don't know how it would get on in that department though.

Comment: This library looks great.  I'll take a closer look at HTTPServer class.  I will use it in a Windows build although it still needs to compile with a Mac build, but this looks promising.  I will research further.